# Boost shared_ptr serialization

Tags: serialization, boost

I've implemented serialization for OpenCVs Mat format as described here: [Serializing OpenCV Mat_<Vec3f>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170745/serializing-opencv-mat-vec3f)

I now got the problem to serialize a shared pointer to a cv::Mat. 
It gives the following errors:

`/usr/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp: In function ‘void boost::serialization::serialize(Archive&, boost::shared_ptr<U>&, unsigned int) [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive, T = boost::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>]’:
/usr/include/boost/serialization/serialization.hpp:128:9`:

instantiated from ‘void >boost::serialization::serialize_adl(Archive&, T&, unsigned int) [with Archive = >boost::archive::text_iarchive, T = boost::shared_ptr >]’
/usr/include/boost/archive/detail/iserializer.hpp:188:5:

instantiated from ‘void >boost::archive::detail::iserializer::load_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_iarchive&, void*, unsigned int) const [with Archive = boost::archive::text_iarchive, T = boost::shared_ptr >]’
recognition2d3d.cpp:227:1: 
instantiated from here

/usr/include/boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp:167:5: error: static assertion failed: "boost::serialization::tracking_level< T >::value != boost::serialization::track_never"`

I tried to use BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING, but could not get it working. Actually i don't really understand what the problem is, reading the boost documentation didn't help to solve this issue.

Comment: If you get this error, then maybe the tracking is disabled for this type? Look for something like `BOOST_CLASS_TRACKING(cv::Mat, boost::serialization::track_never)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't serialize through a shared_ptr unless the object pointed to has a vtable.  Try making the object's destructor virtual.

Edit: alternatively, wrap the object (an OpenCV matrix?) in an object that has a virtual destructor.

Comment: I was able to serialized `boost::shared_ptr` to a class with no virtual destructor `struct A{
 double d_;
 A(double d = 0) : d_(d){}
 template<class Archive> void
 serialize(Archive& ar, unsigned = 0){
  ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("d", d_);
 }
};` both with clang and gcc.