# C++ Opencv - Image handling after get it through sockets

Tags: c++, image, sockets, opencv

My question is about this previous question (unfortunely, the answer doesn't work for me): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314524/c-opencv-image-sending-through-socket

After get the image, the code shows only a grey picture. Am I doing the correct image handling when sending and receive the image?

Sender and receiver codes:

Image sender:

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
// #pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define IMG_BUFLEN 1243897
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main(void)
{
WSADATA wsaData;
int iResult;

SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
struct addrinfo hints;

int iSendResult;
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
unsigned char * imgbuf;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Setup the TCP listening socket
iResult = bind( ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ListenSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// No longer need server socket
closesocket(ListenSocket);

// Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
do {

    iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("SERVER - bytes: %d\n", iResult);
        //char * temp = (char *) malloc(9); memcpy(temp,recvbuf,8);
        if (strcmp(recvbuf, "ASK"))
        {   
            int retTamImg;              
            Mat captureFrame;               
            int imgSize = 0;

            VideoCapture captureDevice;
            captureDevice.open(0);

            if(!captureDevice.isOpened() )
            {
                printf("Nao pode ler o video");
                getchar();                  
            }
            captureDevice>>captureFrame;

            //---------------- SEND IMAGE ----------------//
            if (captureFrame.data != NULL)
            {               
                retTamImg = captureFrame.total() * captureFrame.elemSize();

                iSendResult = send( ClientSocket, (const char *) captureFrame.data, retTamImg, 0 );

                if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                    printf("resposta de pedido de face falhou. erro: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                    closesocket(ClientSocket);
                    WSACleanup();
                    return 1;
                }
                else
                    printf("resposta de pedido de face enviada com suceso. Bytes: %d\n", iSendResult);

            }
            //FECHA CAMERA
            captureDevice.release();

        }
    }
    else if (iResult == 0)
        printf("Connection closing...\n");
    else  {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

} while (iResult > 0);

// shutdown the connection since we're done
iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    getchar();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ClientSocket);
WSACleanup();

return 0;
}
```

Image receiver:

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define IMG_BUFLEN 1243897
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27015"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
WSADATA wsaData;
SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
                *ptr = NULL,
                hints;
char sendbuf [DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
char * imgbuf;
int iResult;
int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

// Initialize Winsock
iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
if (iResult != 0) {
    printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    getchar();
    return 1;
}

ZeroMemory( &hints, sizeof(hints) );
hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

// Resolve the server address and port
iResult = getaddrinfo("127.0.0.1", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
if ( iResult != 0 ) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
for(ptr=result; ptr != NULL ;ptr=ptr->ai_next) {

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
        ptr->ai_protocol);
    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        WSACleanup();
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    // Connect to server.
    iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
        continue;
    }
    break;
}

freeaddrinfo(result);

if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
    printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
    WSACleanup();
    getchar();
    return 1;
}

//----------------- ASK FOR THE IMAGE ----------------------//

    strncpy(sendbuf, "ASK", 8); 

    // Send an initial buffer
    iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send ASK FACE failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("ASK FACE SENT Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

//----------------- GET THE IMAGE ----------------------//

    Mat  img = Mat::zeros( 480,640, CV_8UC3);
    int  imgSize = (int) (img.total()*img.elemSize());
    char * sockData;
    sockData = (char *) malloc (sizeof(char) * imgSize + 1);

   for (int i = 0; i < imgSize; i += iResult) 
   {
       iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, sockData +i, imgSize  - i, 0);
       if ( iResult > 0 )
                printf("CLIENTE - retorno do ASK FACE (%d/%d)- Bytes received: %d\n", i, imgSize, iResult);

        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("CLIENTE - retorno do ASK FACE - Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("CLIENTE - retorno do ASK FACE - error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());

   }

     // Assign pixel value to img
     int iptr=0;
     for (int i = 0;  i < img.rows; i++) {
          for (int j = 0; j < img.cols; j++)    {                                     
               img.at<cv::Vec3b>(i,j) = Vec3b(sockData[iptr+ 0],sockData[iptr+1],sockData[iptr+2]);
               iptr=iptr+3;
           }
      }

     namedWindow("outputCapture", 1);
     imshow("outputCapture", img);
    // imwrite("C:\\Users\\USUARIO\\Documents\\VISAO\\servidor_imagens_cam\\imagem_salva.jpg",img);

// shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
}

// cleanup
closesocket(ConnectSocket);
WSACleanup();

getchar();
return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

After some time here with your code, i finally found the error. You have to use `waitkey()` and not `getchar()`. Besides this, the program it's running fine.