# OpenCV Matrix To Binary Image

Tags: image, opencv, matrix, binary

I have client and server, have an image in client and I want to send this to server. That image is in cv::mat format. Therefore I need to convert this matrix to binary. 
I have tried `memcpy(binImage,matImg.data,sizeof(matImg.data)`
binImage's format is char*

How can i convert this matImg to binImg? I don't have any experience about OpenCV.

Comment: See the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314524/c-opencv-image-sending-through-socket/20321262#20321262 might be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick:

```
memcpy(binImage, matImg.data, matImg.step.p[0]*matImg.rows)
```

However, I think you can avoid the copy and work directly with `matImg.data`.

Comment: @Darth This is only the instruction for `memcpy`. Did you allocated `binImage` with enough space ? Did you initialized `matImg` ?