# C++ Socket libraries are not being identified by the compiler

Tags: c++, sockets

I am trying to to learn how to stream image frames via UDP in C++ and I was following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVq4aecyQto) for the server part to receive my frames, this tutorial clearly uses code from question stackoverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314524/c-opencv-image-sending-through-socket). However, after following up both sources, whenever I attempt to load my libraries in geany/c++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h> 
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

#define width 320
#define height 240
int imgSize;
int bytes=0;
bool running = true;
char key;
const int ah = 230400;
    
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    
    SOCKET server;
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(9999);
    connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me the following errors:

```
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:27:2: error: ‘SOCKET’ was not declared in this scope
   27 |  SOCKET server;
      |  ^~~~~~
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:28:2: error: ‘SOCKADDR_IN’ was not declared in this scope
   28 |  SOCKADDR_IN addr;
      |  ^~~~~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:29:2: error: ‘server’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘servent’?
   29 |  server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
      |  ^~~~~~
      |  servent
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:30:2: error: ‘addr’ was not declared in this scope
   30 |  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
      |  ^~~~
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:30:25: error: ‘inet_addr’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘in6_addr’?
   30 |  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
      |                         ^~~~~~~~~
      |                         in6_addr
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:33:19: error: ‘SOCKADDR’ was not declared in this scope
   33 |  connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
      |                   ^~~~~~~~
/home/pi/Documentos/cam.cpp:33:29: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   33 |  connect(server, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, sizeof(addr));
```

Forgive my ignorance, I'd like to know what is the right way to create a UDP socket for a specific IP/Port

Comment: I believe that's based on the Windows API, so you'll have to port it to normal BSD Sockets API first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `SOCKET` or `SOCKADDR_IN` which is Microsoft dedicated but I see Linux headers.

You need to select what you want to do:

1. You need code only for Windows.
2. You need code only for Linux.
3. You need a cross-platform code.

Your approach somehow differs based on what you want to do.

If your code is supposed to work on **Windows** only, replace:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
```

with:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
```

and also add `WSAStartup()` and `WSACleanup()` to your code (I'm almost sure you will miss this part if you are socket programming on Windows). You also need to link your code with `Ws2_32.lib`.

If you are coding for **Linux**, replace `SOCKET` with `int`, `SOCKADDR_IN` with `sockaddr_in`, and `SOCKADDR` with `sockaddr` and try again.

Comment: im on raspberry pi/bullseye 64

Comment: @xnok then go with linux one.

Answer (score 0):

That's WinSock code. And techniques and functions available there aren't 100% matching between POSIX and WinSock. I wouldn't recommend to define own version of Windows types, that would be misleading and hard to see which part of code were refactored. Rather go with something like:

```
#ifdef WINDOWS_PC /** some predefined  macro */
typedef SOCKET socket_t;
#else
#  ifdef POSIX /** some predefined  macro */
typedef int    socket_t;
#  endif
#endif
```

POSIX-compatible types relevant to `SOCKADDR_IN` and `SOCKADDR` were `sockaddr_in` and `sockaddr`, they were to be available in WinSock2.

WinSock functionality uses  a special function for getting error codes instead of `errno` which is used in POSIX. There is no `ioctl` in Winsock function, instead there is not quite same `ioctlsocket`, Windows `closesocket` would be replaced just by `close` because POSIX socket is either a file(stream) or block device, `read`/`write` can be used on it.