# Merge several boost serialized OpenCV Mats

Tags: c++, opencv, serialization, boost, mat

Follow up the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170745/serializing-opencv-mat-vec3f) of Serializing OpenCV Mat_

My task is I have multiple OpenCV Mats that are serialized. Now I want to merge all those Mats. I can do this by deserialize these binaries into Mats and use `push_back` method to merge them. However, for my own reason, I have to merge them in binary format first before deserialize.

How can I merge these binaries so that in the end, I can call my same deserialization to get the whole big Mat?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without using *boost*. Following the serialization approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32357875/5008845), you can append the data of your matrix at the end of the file, taking care of increasing the number of rows of the final matrix accordingly.

Here's a working example, where `matappend` does the job. I'll put also the `matread` and `matwrite` functions for completeness:

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void matwrite(const string& filename, const Mat& mat)
{
    ofstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Header
    int type = mat.type();
    int channels = mat.channels();
    fs.write((char*)&mat.rows, sizeof(int));    // rows
    fs.write((char*)&mat.cols, sizeof(int));    // cols
    fs.write((char*)&type, sizeof(int));        // type
    fs.write((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));    // channels

    // Data
    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
    }
    else
    {
        int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * mat.cols;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
        }
    }
}

Mat matread(const string& filename)
{
    ifstream fs(filename, fstream::binary);

    // Header
    int rows, cols, type, channels;
    fs.read((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));         // rows
    fs.read((char*)&cols, sizeof(int));         // cols
    fs.read((char*)&type, sizeof(int));         // type
    fs.read((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));     // channels

    // Data
    Mat mat(rows, cols, type);
    fs.read((char*)mat.data, CV_ELEM_SIZE(type) * rows * cols);

    return mat;
}

void matappend(const string& filename, const Mat& mat)
{
    fstream fs(filename, fstream::binary | fstream::in);

    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/2390938/5008845
    if (fs.peek() == fstream::traits_type::eof())
    {
        // The file is empty, write (same as matwrite)

        fs.close();
        fs.open(filename, fstream::binary | fstream::out);

        // Header
        int type = mat.type();
        int channels = mat.channels();
        fs.write((char*)&mat.rows, sizeof(int));    // rows
        fs.write((char*)&mat.cols, sizeof(int));    // cols
        fs.write((char*)&type, sizeof(int));        // type
        fs.write((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));    // channels
    }
    else
    {
        // The file is not empty, append

        fs.close();
        fs.open(filename, fstream::binary | fstream::out | fstream::in);

        // Read Header
        int rows, cols, type, channels;
        fs.read((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));         // rows
        fs.read((char*)&cols, sizeof(int));         // cols
        fs.read((char*)&type, sizeof(int));         // type
        fs.read((char*)&channels, sizeof(int));     // channels

        // Consistency check
        CV_Assert((cols == mat.cols) && (type == mat.type()) && (channels == mat.channels()));

        // Go to beginning of file
        fs.seekp(fstream::beg);

        // Overwrite the number of rows
        rows += mat.rows;
        fs.write((char*)&rows, sizeof(int));    // rows

        // Go to end of file
        fs.seekp(0, fstream::end);
    }

    // Write data
    if (mat.isContinuous())
    {
        fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(0), (mat.dataend - mat.datastart));
    }
    else
    {
        int rowsz = CV_ELEM_SIZE(mat.type()) * mat.cols;
        for (int r = 0; r < mat.rows; ++r)
        {
            fs.write(mat.ptr<char>(r), rowsz);
        }
    }
    fs.close();
}



int main()
{
    // Save the random generated data

    Mat1b m1 = (Mat1b(2, 2) << 1, 2, 3, 4);
    Mat1b m2 = (Mat1b(3, 2) << 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10);

    matappend("raw.bin", m1);
    matappend("raw.bin", m2);

    Mat m3 = matread("raw.bin");

    // m3: 
    // 1 2
    // 3 4
    // 5 6
    // 7 8
    // 9 10


    return 0;
}
```